# php take data from mysql db and store them in xml file

Tags: php, mysql, xml

i write a php file to connect in a mysql db and take back the last insert. i want this last insert to store in xml file but i didnt find any solution. i want the values from mysql to store them in a XML file but i dont know the way.my code is this:

```
'<?php 
 mysql_connect("000.000.000.000", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("arduino_db") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `weather` order by `add` desc limit 1") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 echo "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<th>currentDirection :</th> <td>".$info['currentDirection'] . "</td> "; 
 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<th>light :</th> <td>".$info['light'] . "</td> "; 
 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<th>pressure :</th> <td>".$info['pressure'] . "</td> "; 
 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<th>lhumidity :</th> <td>".$info['humidity'] . "</td> "; 
 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<th>tempC :</th> <td>".$info['tempC'] . "</td> "; 
 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<th>rainin :</th> <td>".$info['rainin'] . "</td> "; 
 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<th>windSpeed :</th> <td>".$info['windSpeed'] . "</td> "; 
 } 
 echo "</table>"; 

 ?> '
```

Comment: posting your db credentials isn't the best thing to do...

Comment: And what is your problem ? And what is your question ? Do you get any errors ? What is the expected result and what do you actually get ? As a side remark, this is HTML, not XML (although purists could argue on that :-) )

Comment: i want to store this data in a xml file but i dont know the way

Comment: You should use PDO or MYSQLi. http://si1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php http://si1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @user3819412 i have updated my answer. It should work now. Check.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml_file = new DOMDocument();

$windSpeed = $info['windSpeed'];

$xml_windSpeed = $xml->createElement("windSpeed");
$xml_windSpeed->appendChild($windSpeed);
$xml_file->appendChild( $xml_windSpeed );

$xml_file->save("/documents/windSpeed.xml"); //Put there your path
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i take this error Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\connect_db_take_data.php on line 28

Comment: @user3819412 First you have to create an element in order to append it later.

Answer (score 0):

**1. The answer to your question - UPDATE**

With rows:

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("000.000.000.000", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("arduino_db") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `weather` order by `add` desc limit 1") or die(mysql_error()); 

$xml = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "UTF-8" );

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{
    $row = $xml->createElement( 'row' . $i++ . '' );
    $xml_row->appendChild( $row );
    
    $currentDirection = $xml->createElement( 'currentDirection', '' . $info['currentDirection'] . '' );
    $xml_row->appendChild( $currentDirection );
    $light = $xml->createElement( 'light', '' . $info['light'] . '' );
    $xml_row->appendChild( $light );
    $pressure = $xml->createElement( 'pressure', '' . $info['pressure'] . '' );
    $xml_row->appendChild( $pressure );
    $humidity = $xml->createElement( 'humidity', '' . $info['humidity'] . '' );
    $xml_row->appendChild( $humidity );
    $tempC = $xml->createElement( 'tempC', '' . $info['tempC'] . '' );
    $xml_row->appendChild( $tempC );
    $rainin = $xml->createElement( 'rainin', '' . $info['rainin'] . '' );
    $xml_row->appendChild( $rainin );
    $windSpeed = $xml->createElement( 'windSpeed', '' . $info['windSpeed'] . '' );
    $xml_row->appendChild( $windSpeed );
} 

$xml_file_contents = $xml->saveXML();
$filename = 'your_xml_file_name.xml';

// Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
if (is_writable($filename)) {

    // In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
    // The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
    // that's where $xml_file_contents will go when we fwrite() it.
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
     echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
     exit;
    }

    // Write $xml_file_contents to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($handle, $xml_file_contents) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
    exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($xml_file_contents) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}

?>
```

**1. The answer to your question**

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("000.000.000.000", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("arduino_db") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `weather` order by `add` desc limit 1") or die(mysql_error()); 

$xml = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "UTF-8" );

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{
    $currentDirection = $xml->createElement( 'currentDirection', '' . $info['currentDirection'] . '' );
    $xml->appendChild( $currentDirection );
    $light = $xml->createElement( 'light', '' . $info['light'] . '' );
    $xml->appendChild( $light );
    $pressure = $xml->createElement( 'pressure', '' . $info['pressure'] . '' );
    $xml->appendChild( $pressure );
    $humidity = $xml->createElement( 'humidity', '' . $info['humidity'] . '' );
    $xml->appendChild( $humidity );
    $tempC = $xml->createElement( 'tempC', '' . $info['tempC'] . '' );
    $xml->appendChild( $tempC );
    $rainin = $xml->createElement( 'rainin', '' . $info['rainin'] . '' );
    $xml->appendChild( $rainin );
    $windSpeed = $xml->createElement( 'windSpeed', '' . $info['windSpeed'] . '' );
    $xml->appendChild( $windSpeed );
} 

$xml_file_contents = $xml->saveXML();
$filename = 'your_xml_file_name.xml';

// Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
if (is_writable($filename)) {

    // In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
    // The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
    // that's where $xml_file_contents will go when we fwrite() it.
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
     echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
     exit;
    }

    // Write $xml_file_contents to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($handle, $xml_file_contents) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
    exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($xml_file_contents) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}

?>
```

**2. More about writing `XML` files**

```
// "Create" the document.
$xml = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "ISO-8859-15" ); // or 'UTF-8'

// Create some elements.
$xml_album = $xml->createElement( "Album" );
$xml_track = $xml->createElement( "Track", "The ninth symphony" );

// Set the attributes.
$xml_track->setAttribute( "length", "0:01:15" );
$xml_track->setAttribute( "bitrate", "64kb/s" );
$xml_track->setAttribute( "channels", "2" );

// Create another element, just to show you can add any (realistic to computer) number of sublevels.
$xml_note = $xml->createElement( "Note", "The last symphony composed by Ludwig van Beethoven." );

// Append the whole bunch.
$xml_track->appendChild( $xml_note );
$xml_album->appendChild( $xml_track );

// Repeat the above with some different values..
$xml_track = $xml->createElement( "Track", "Highway Blues" );

$xml_track->setAttribute( "length", "0:01:33" );
$xml_track->setAttribute( "bitrate", "64kb/s" );
$xml_track->setAttribute( "channels", "2" );
$xml_album->appendChild( $xml_track );

$xml->appendChild( $xml_album );

// Parse the XML.
print $xml->saveXML();
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

```
createElement( name, value ) // just to clarify how this will look in an xml file: <name>value</name>
```

**3. more about writing normal text files**

This is the minimum required code, to write some data to a file:

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '' . $your_text . '');
fclose($fp);
```

But use something like this, for better security:

```
<?php
$filename = 'test.txt';
$somecontent = "Add this to the file\n";

// Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
if (is_writable($filename)) {

    // In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
    // The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
    // that's where $somecontent will go when we fwrite() it.
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
       echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
       exit;
    }

    // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
      echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
      exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}
?>
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

You can write objects/arrays to a file with `JSON` (which serializes when writing and deserializes when reading the data): https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Check these 2 links also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

And then you can read your file with :

```
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt');
```

or to read only a part of the file:

```
<?php
// Read 14 characters starting from the 21st character
$section = file_get_contents('./people.txt', NULL, NULL, 20, 14);
var_dump($section);
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad and you might just have it more easy to isolate sub-problems here. Stackoverflow works best asking a single, concrete question.

- [How do I get the last inserted ID of a MySQL table in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1685860/367456)
- [How to append to a XML file with PHP preferably with SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7098093/367456)

So if you divide your problem, you can more easily solve the overall problem by solving the sub-steps. Not only is that easier then for you, but also the format of Stackoverflow requires that you ask a single, concrete programming question at a time. Otherwise the answers tend to become bloated and aren't helpful any longer. Because they become unclear over time, your question is easy to misread etc. .

I hope these two example questions leave you at least the pointers to write the code you need.

I also highly recommend you to use a more modern database API (preferable [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo)), as it's easier to deal with (e.g. overall API and the looping is much improved).